# Calculating point on Circle

Tags: javascript, geometry, trigonometry

I am aware of plenty of articles on this topic on the Internet, but I have not managed to solve my problem. I think me trigonometry calculations are correct, but perhaps I am messing something up within JavaScript.

My goals is to calculate the point on circle (x,y) so that I can move my `sliderHead` to that position. For this I need to calculate the angle between the pressed / clicked points on my circle - I use `atan2` for that. Next I use simple trigonometry to calculate the actually X and Y:

```
let y = -Math.ceil(radius * Math.cos(deg));
let x = Math.ceil(radius * Math.sin(deg));
```

I understand that I need to invert the `cosine` and `sine`, because my starting position is actually at 90 degrees and not 0 and I turn CLOCKWISE and not COUNTERCLOCKWISE, which maths suggests.

**The starting values are 0, becuse the initial value of the `sliderHead` is at center of the Circle.** The starting value is not actual 0, 0px, but center of the parent div.

As you will see on below picture, I am not doing it correct, the sliderHead is behind the bar.

[image]

Here is the code where I calculate the point x,y:

```
 testCalc(event) {
        let deg = Math.atan2(event.pageY - this.centerY, event.pageX - this.centerX);

        console.log(deg);

        let radius = this.options.radius;

        let y = -Math.ceil(radius * Math.cos(deg));
        let x = Math.ceil(radius * Math.sin(deg));      

        return {
            "x": x + "px",
            "y": y + "px"
        };

    }
```

And here is the positioning of the sliderHead element within my HTML:
[image]

Here is how I translate the `sliderHead`:

```
    moveSliderHeadPosition(point) {
           this.sliderHead.style.transform = "translate(" + point["x"] + "," + point["y"] + ")";
   }
```

As said, I exhausted all of my options with trying to solve this.

Comment: Is your slider head always on the circle after a click? Is it off by a certain ratio or amount (angle-wise or pixel-wise)? Better yet, can you make a snippet or a StackBlitz project for this?

Comment: Slider is always on the circle, just not at the correct values like the 'fill' part of the slider is. I have never made StackBlitz project, let me check and I will try to come up with it.

Comment: If you use the mouse to position the sliderHead and the ring around the circle, does one of them correspond to the mouse position? Look at my example to see what I mean.

Answer (score 2):

Nice on the use of atan2! Looking at your code it looks right to me, though maybe it's as simple as needing to subtract half the size of the sliderHead?

Here's an example that I put together to test it:

```js
function showCoords(event) {
  var x = event.clientX;
  var y = event.clientY;
  var xn = x / window.innerWidth;
  var yn = y / window.innerHeight;
  var result = Math.atan2(x, y);
  var coor = `X: ${x}, Y: ${y} > X1: ${xn.toFixed(2)}, Y1: ${yn.toFixed(
    2
  )} ~ ${result.toFixed(
    2)}`;
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = coor;
}

function moveGrabber(event) {
  // get our grabber and track as well as their bounding rectangles
  var grabber = document.querySelector(".grabber");
  var grabberRect = grabber.getBoundingClientRect();
  var track = document.querySelector(".track");
  var trackRect = track.getBoundingClientRect();
  var trackRadius = trackRect.width / 2;

  // get our window center
  var windowCenterX = window.innerWidth / 2;
  var windowCenterY = window.innerHeight / 2;

  // get the angle around the window center
  var x = event.clientX;
  var y = event.clientY;
  var angle = Math.atan2(x - windowCenterX, y - windowCenterY);

  // get the point on the circle
  var circleX = Math.sin(angle) * trackRadius + windowCenterX;
  var circleY = Math.cos(angle) * trackRadius + windowCenterY;

  // subtract half the size of the grabber so that it is centered on the track
  var posX = circleX - grabberRect.width / 2;
  var posY = circleY - grabberRect.height / 2;

  grabber.style.left = `${posX}px`;
  grabber.style.top = `${posY}px`;
}

function moveGrabberWithX(event) {
  // get our grabber and track as well as their bounding rectangles
  var grabber = document.querySelector(".grabber");
  var grabberRect = grabber.getBoundingClientRect();
  var track = document.querySelector(".track");
  var trackRect = track.getBoundingClientRect();
  var trackRadius = trackRect.width / 2;

  // get the mouse position and the normalized version in the range of [0,1]
  var x = event.clientX;
  var xn = x / window.innerWidth;

  // get the center of the window
  var windowCenterX = window.innerWidth / 2;
  var windowCenterY = window.innerHeight / 2;

  // get the point on the circle
  // this uses the normalized x position of the mouse [0,1]
  // and multiplies it by 2PI which gives you a circle
  var circleX = Math.sin(xn * Math.PI * 2) * trackRadius + windowCenterX;
  var circleY = Math.cos(xn * Math.PI * 2) * trackRadius + windowCenterY;

  // subtract half the size of the grabber so that it is centered on the track
  var posX = circleX - grabberRect.width / 2;
  var posY = circleY - grabberRect.height / 2;

  grabber.style.left = `${posX}px`;
  grabber.style.top = `${posY}px`;
}
```

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}
.center {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  background: gray;
}

.track {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  background: rgb(13, 88, 134);
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.grabber {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  background: coral;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.label {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  /* display: flex; */
}
p {
  background: darkgray;
  font-family: "Courier New", Courier, monospace;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <title>Static Template</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="center" onmousemove="moveGrabber(event); showCoords(event);">
      <div class="track" />
      <div class="grabber" />
    </div>
    <div class="label">
      <p id="demo" />
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing. The snippet works for me. However, I have to find out the way to make my code to work.  Will try to get some ideas from your code.

Comment: I think my atan2 function is not working as I intend it too.. becase when I convert it to degrees, the degrees are always around 100, even though if I go all around the circl. So I assume there is some mistake at the definition of Y and X for the atan2 function.

Comment: Maybe your page is scrolled? Can you try with clientX and clientY?

Comment: Also, it could be the absolute positioning + the translate, which is fine, but I can't tell from the info that you posted what the correct values for the dial should be. I'd think left and top would correspond to the center of your progress and then you adjust the translate, but not sure. Post a stackblitz or codesandbox

Comment: Is this is working for you please accept, otherwise happy to help if you can provide more context :D

Comment: I will try to provide my entire code, because the answer does not help me specifically. Although it works, but I have to make it work for my project, which I cannot just erase and start from scratch. I will look into StackBlitz and CodeSandbox to try and share it here.

Answer (score 0):

Try multiplying or dividing the calculated angle by `57.2957795` (a conversion between degrees and radians).

Comment: I tried, it does not work. If I multiply it, the sliderHead moves faster and in front of the actual values. If I divide it, the sliderHead does not move at all.